# Populating pandas dataframe by searching data in substring of string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, pandas

Suppose a list of strings:

```
lst1 = ['A1 B1 C1', 'A2 B2 D1', 'S1 M1 A3', 'A4 B3 G1','H1 K1 W1']
```

I want to create a table by searching a specific value within each string(if available) then populate a pandas dataframe .

Like so:

```
         'A'     'B'     'C'      'D'
string1   A1      B1      C1      Nan
string2   A2      B2     Nan       D1
string3   A3      Nan    Nan      Nan
string4   A4      B3     Nan      Nan
string5   Nan     Nan    Nan      Nan
```

In order to search within each string, I split each of them into a list making it a nested list in order to run a for loop within each string to search. My RegEx game is not too strong but I think this can be done with a good handle on RegEx.

My current code :

```
import pandas as pd
lst1 = ['A1 B1 C1', 'A2 B2 D1', 'S1 M1 A3', 'A4 B3 G1','H1 K1 W1']
modlst1 = []
for each in lst1:
    modlst1.append(each.split())

rows = range(len(modlst1)) ### rows for each string
cols = ['A','B','C','D']   ### cols for each string
df = pd.DataFrame(index = rows, columns = cols)
df = df.fillna(0)

### Populating values
for each in rows:
    for stuff in modlst1[each]:
        if stuff.startswith('A'):
           df['A'] = stuff
        elif stuff.startswith('B'):
           df['B'] = stuff
        elif stuff.startswith('C'):
           df['C'] = stuff
        elif stuff.startswith('D'):
           df['D'] = stuff
```

I'm very new to Python so I am still learning string manipulation and search and find. I am sure there has to be a better way to do this. My solution is not working as same values keep populating in my dataframe, when I try to put them in dataframe. But when I do:

```
        if stuff.startswith('A'):
           print(stuff)
```

loop runs fine and I get different values of "A","B","C","D". 
For eg: *(i DON'T WANT THIS)*

```
         'A'     'B'     'C'      'D'
string1   A1      B1      C1      Nan
string2   A1      B1      C1       D1
string3   A1      B1      C1       D1
string4   A1      B1      C1       D1
string5   A1      B1      C1       D1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

lst1 = ['A1 B1 C1', 'A2 B2 D1', 'S1 M1 A3', 'A4 B3 G1','H1 K1 W1']

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']   ### cols for each string
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

### Populating values
for elt in lst1:
    new = {}
    for sub_elt in elt.split(" "):
        if sub_elt[0] in cols:
            new[sub_elt[0]] = sub_elt
    df = df.append(pd.Series(new), ignore_index=True)
```

Feel free to ask if some part is unclear

Comment: Thank you. Although when I apply it my actual data I get a traceback on line: if sub_elt[0] in cols: 
IndexError: string index out of range. 
My data is exactly of this format, so I can't figure out the reason behind this error

Comment: Hard to tell without the data. Maybe you have a trailing space before your first element?

Comment: I thought that would be it. But I tried messing with data to test my theory but getting the same error. Can you perhaps explain what if sub_elt[0] in cols: is essentially doing?